# Different results with id function and invalid xml:id attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, saxon, basex

I am wondering what is the right way an XQuery implementation should do with the `id` function and an element having an `xml:id` attribute being invalid e.g. `<foo xml:id="2">foo 2</foo>`.

A simple test case like

```
document {<root>
    <foo xml:id="f1">foo 1</foo>
    <foo xml:id="2">foo 2</foo>
    <foo xml:id="f3">foo 3</foo>
    <foo xml:id="f4">foo 4</foo>
</root>}/id(('f1', '2', 'f4'))
```

gives me different results, BaseX returns three elements

```
<foo xml:id="f1">foo 1</foo>
<foo xml:id="2">foo 2</foo>
<foo xml:id="f4">foo 4</foo>
```

so it doesn't care that `2` is not a valid ID value.

Saxon (9.9 HE Java) returns only the two elements with valid ids

```
<foo xml:id="f1">foo 1</foo>
<foo xml:id="f4">foo 4</foo>
```

XmlPrime rejects the query with

> XQDY0091: A constructed xml:id attribute may not have value '2'.  It
>   must be an NCName.

This seems to be permitted as an option in https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#ERRXQDY0091.

As for the `id` function itself, it seems to spell out in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-id that "If any of the tokens is not a lexically valid IDREF (that is, if it is not lexically an xs:NCName), it is ignored" so based on that Saxon is doing it right while BaseX should ignore the `2` argument in the argument sequence to the `if` function.

Is that the right conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your reading of the spec is correct. The processor isn't required to reject the attribute at the time it is constructed, but it is required that the id() function ignores it if it's not valid.

The XQuery spec actually says in §3.9.1.1:

*If the attribute name is xml:id, then xml:id processing is performed as defined in [XML ID]. This ensures that the attribute has the type xs:ID and that its value is properly normalized. If an error is encountered during xml:id processing, an implementation may raise a dynamic error [err:XQDY0091].*

*If the attribute name is xml:id, the is-id property of the resulting attribute node is set to true; otherwise the is-id property is set to false. The is-idrefs property of the attribute node is unconditionally set to false.*

Arguably this is a little incomplete: it says that xml:id processing "is performed"; it doesn't say what the processor should do if xml:id processing fails and the implementation chooses not to raise the dynamic error. It also suggests that the attribute should be typed as xs:ID even by a non-validating processor, but that makes no sense because there are plenty of statements throughout the spec that with a non-validating processor, all nodes will be untyped.

Wherever possible Saxon tries to do things the same way for XQuery and XSLT, provided that the specs permit this. So it's always worth seeing what both specs say. XSLT says this:

*If the name of a constructed attribute is xml:id, the processor must perform attribute value normalization by effectively applying the normalize-space function to the value of the attribute, and the resulting attribute node must be given the is-id property. This applies whether the attribute is constructed using the xsl:attribute instruction or whether it is constructed using an attribute of a literal result element. This does not imply any constraints on the value of the attribute, or on its uniqueness, and it does not affect the type annotation of the attribute, unless the containing document is validated.*

*Note:*

*The effect of setting the is-id property is that the parent element can be located within the containing document by use of the idFO30 function. In effect, XSLT when constructing a document performs some of the functions of an xml:id processor, as defined in [xml:id]; the other aspects of xml:id processing are performed during validation.*

So XSLT has chosen to NOT validate the value of the xml:id attribute unless schema validation is being performed on the constructed tree; and that's how Saxon handles it.

Comment: "it is required that the id() function ignores it if it's not valid": I have browsed some test cases for `fn:id` in the XQuery test suite but I can't seem to find one like the posted sample, it seems there are only test cases "ignoring" invalid arguments where there is no element with that invalid id anyway. Not sure whether there is a compatible way for a test case to specify that the result can either be XQDY0091 or an empty sequence for e.g. `document{<foo xml:id="2"/>}/id('2')`.

Comment: I've committed a couple of new tests fn-id-24 and fn-id-25: https://github.com/w3c/qt3tests/blob/master/fn/id.xml